# Define unique Environment variables for all tasks in ECS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS service that will be running many instances of one task. All these instances use the exact same task definition but all need to be provided a specific environment variable INDEX that is unique to that instance. I would like the service to monitor each instance and restart it with the same environment variable value if it fails (I.E. If a task with INDEX=555 fails, I would like the service to spin up a new task with INDEX=555 to replace it). Currently I only see the option to set environment variables in the task definition itself, which would require me to create many versions of the exact same task (and the corresponding service as well) with the only difference being the environment variable (this seems wasteful and would clutter the task definition list and service list in that cluster).

In short I want to configure my ECS service such that I can provide a list of values for a specific environment variable along with one task definition and have it create a 1:1 map of a task instance to environment variable. Is it possible to do so? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Important Note: This service is running on Fargate and not EC2 Instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do this for ECS Service. The ECS services are meant to run **exact copies** of same tasks which are disposable, exchangeable and scalable.

However, you can provide overwrites for the varaibles for tasks **outside of a service**, which you can do using [run-task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html) or [start-task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/start-task.html) with `--overrides` of AWS CLI or equivalent in any AWS SDK.

Comment: If I instantiate these tasks like outside of a service will they still restart even if the task instance goes down? If I set the desired status as running, will the cluster still restart the task instance (with the same environmental variable override)?

Comment: @Prad Sadly they will not restart. For that you need service. If you want to use service you need to create services for each task definition with different env variables. In the service you can't overwrite any task parameters.